# How can I find face shape using Open CV,dlib and forehead region?

Tags: python, image-processing, face

I want to find face shape for hair recommendation and I can't find a forhead area using dlib,Opencv in python. Thresholding is a way to find?
How can I detect forehead area and find face shape?

Anyone know what can i use?

Comment: maybe you could try to ask on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)